# Работа с дочерними элементами JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу получить значение input hidden средствами JQuery в рамках предложенного listener. Приведенный ниже скрипт выдает undefined. В чём ошибка?

```js
$('.mdl-list__item').click(function (point) {
    var distrib = $(point).children('.name').val();
    console.log(distrib);
    // undefined
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="mdl-list__item">
  <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
    <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-icon">
      local_cafe
    </i>
    <span class="mdl-badge" data-badge="0">
      Пивоварня 3
    </span>
  </span>
  <input type="hidden" class='name' value="beer3">
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При клике, `point` является событием текущего объекта, в нём нет метода `children`. Получить текущий элемент jquery можно через `$(this)`

```
$(this).children('.name').val();
```

jquery

```js
$('.mdl-list__item').click(function(point) {
    var distrib = $(this).find('input').val();
    console.log(distrib);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<li class="mdl-list__item">
  <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
    <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-icon">local_cafe</i>
    <span class="mdl-badge" data-badge="0">Пивоварня 3</span>
  </span>
  <input type="hidden" class='name' value="beer3">
</li>
```

---

javascript

```js
function f(e) {
  distrib = e.querySelector('input').value;
  console.log(distrib);
}
```

```html
<li class="mdl-list__item" onclick='f(this)'>
  <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
    <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-icon">local_cafe</i>
    <span class="mdl-badge" data-badge="0">Пивоварня 3</span>
  </span>
  <input type="hidden" class='name' value="beer3">
</li>
```

Comment: уточните, почему в присвоении переменной $this?

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, элемент, по которому кликнули `$('.mdl-list__item')`

Comment: спасибо и за чистый). А есть вариант с отсутствием "вкроплений" чистого js в html? Просто в самом проекте (php) это два разных файла, и концепция состоит именно в полном разделении кода..

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, `document.querySelector('.mdl-list__item').onclick = function() { console.log(this.querySelector('input').value); }`

Answer (score 2):

Стоит обратиться к [справке по функции click](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

В ней описан параметр *handler*

> **handler**
>   Type: Function( Event eventObject )
>   A function to execute each time the event is triggered.

Таким образом видно, что параметр у коллбэка - это объект *Event*, а не элемент по которому кликнули.

Поэтому при использовании на нем *$(point).children* - вернет пустую коллекцию.

В обработчиках `jQuery` как правило `this` устанавливается в текущий элемент, поэтому использовать нужно именно его, либо [event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/), если нет вложенных элементов.

Comment: Можно в консоль вывести event и посмотреть что он содержит `console.log(event)`

Comment: @Doofy, не понял комментарий

Comment: Это для Вячеслава)

Comment: @Doofy, да, посмотрел, интересно. При этом вариант с $(this).children у меня также работает... Что вроде никак не противоречит Вашим комментариям

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, отличие `children` От `find` в том, что первая функция смотрит только прямых детей, на первом уровне, а вторая - на всех уровнях, так как тут `input` - лежит непосредственно в контейнере - разницы по результату может не быть